# react-native-audio-recorder-player: Cannot read property 'startRecorder' of undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, audio

my code is working perfectly in android platform but in ios i get : `unhandled Promise Rejection: Cannot read property 'startRecorder' of undefined`  error

i was looking for an audio recorder package for react-native, this package seems to be best solution, but it's not working in ios platform

```
  const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
  class QuestionSection extends Component {
    async onRecordPressed() {
      if (await this.requestPermissions()) {
        console.warn('start');
        await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
    }
  }
```

Comment: HI ali, can you please post the error you're facing?

Comment: it's Possible unhandled promise rejection. TypeError:  Cannot read property 'start recorder of undefined... the weird thing is in android i don't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in Constructor and Enjoy

```
 this.audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
this.audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09);
```

Use in hooks add these lines in UseEffect

```
audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();
audioRecorderPlayer.setSubscriptionDuration(0.09);
```